# VBscript that looks correct but errors 800A09D5

Tags: vbscript

I Have been searching for an answer to this but it looks like my vbscript is correct. The macro is not in a module of the same name "MasterSAP". Can’t see what is wrong, you would think this is simple, but I can’t figure it out.

```
Dim accessApp
set accessApp = createobject("Access.Application")
accessApp.OpenCurrentDataBase("S:\Salem\SCHED\SeesStuff\Resources\MasterSAPData.accdb")

accessApp.Run "MasterSAP"
AccessApp.Quit
Set accessApp = nothing
```

Comment: Make sure `MasterSAP` sub isn't in a module of the same name, ie MasterSAP.

Comment: It is not....but thanks...

Comment: Then edit that info into the question as that is the most frequent cause of this error.

Comment: That is not what @Noodles is asking. Check that the procedure containing the code *(not the macro)* in the `Module` whether it be a `Sub` or `Function` is not named the same as the name of the `Module`.

Comment: It may just be a coincidence but you have exactly the same issue as this page [script, module and function](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=252614) using the same variable names etc.

Comment: Thank You @Noodles.  Sorry for the misinterpretation Noodles.  I saw similar posts to your link Lankymart and misinterpreted what they were saying.  Sometimes it just takes a certain word that someone says to show you that you are being a lunkhead....thanks again.

Comment: @lankymart.  Thanks and please read above comment...it only lets you notify one responder per comment.

Comment: No problem @GeorgeS glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to guess because the rest of the code is missing but you should have a procedure in a standard module that `Run()` is calling if you don't and you are just passing the name of a macro this error will occur.

You should have your code in a standard module with the following definition;

```vb
Public Sub MasterSAP()
    ...
End Sub
```

You also want to be careful that this procedure is not placed inside a standard module called `MasterSAP` as this can also cause the error as both the procedure and the module will share the same namespace.